# Print characters at even and odd indices from a String

Tags: string, scala, functional-programming

Using scala, how to print string in even and odd indices of a given string? I am aware of the imperative approach using `var`.  I am looking for an approach that uses immutability, avoids side-effects (of course, until need to print result) and concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tail-recursive solution returning even and odd chars `(List[Char], List[Char])` in one go

```
def f(in: String): (List[Char], List[Char]) = {
  @tailrec def run(s: String, idx: Int, accEven: List[Char], accOdd: List[Char]): (List[Char], List[Char]) = {
    if (idx < 0) (accEven, accOdd)
    else if (idx % 2 == 0) run(s, idx - 1, s.charAt(idx) :: accEven, accOdd)
    else run(s, idx - 1, accEven, s.charAt(idx) :: accOdd)
  }
  run(in, in.length - 1, Nil, Nil)
}
```

which could be printed like so

```
val (even, odd) = f("abcdefg")
println(even.mkString)
```

Comment: Mostly style, but I prefer to use `::` for prepping elements to a **List**, it makes obvious at first glance that the operation is a prepend and that the prepended collection is a list and no any other thing for which prepends may be linear. _(btw, nice idea to start at the end so the built list is already in order)_

Answer (score 3):

Another way to explore is using `zipWithIndex`

```scala
def printer(evenOdd: Int) {
    val str = "1234"
    str.zipWithIndex.foreach { i =>
      i._2 % 2 match {
        case x if x == evenOdd => print(i._1)
        case _ =>
      }
    }
  }
```

In this case you can check the results by using the printer function

```sh
scala> printer(1)
24
scala> printer(0)
13
```

`.zipWithIndex` takes a `List` and returns tuples of the elements coupled with their index. Knowing that a `String` is a list of `Char`

Looking at `str`

```sh
scala> val str = "1234"
str: String = 1234

str.zipWithIndex
res: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[(Char, Int)] = Vector((1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3))
```

Lastly, as you only need to print, using `foreach` instead of `map` is more ideal as you aren't expecting values to be returned

Comment: I would suggest passing a **Boolean** instead of an **Int**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `sliding` function, which is quite simple:

```
scala> "abcdefgh".sliding(1,2).mkString("")
res16: String = aceg

scala> "abcdefgh".tail.sliding(1,2).mkString("")
res17: String = bdfh
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val s = "abcd"
// ac
(0 until s.length by 2).map(i => s(i))
// bd
(1 until s.length by 2).map(i => s(i))
```

just pure functions with map operator

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please explain the ```s(_)`` ? Can you please post a desugarred equivalent code for me ?

Comment: @dexter2305 Don't use this if this is an assignment or performance sensitive. You should really avoid the random access `s(i)` for strings as this is `O(n)`

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh . I thought `s(i)` calls `String::charAt` under the hood which is constant time. Could you elaborate more on why this is O(n) ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh **Strings** are just fancy wrappers over **Array[Char]**, they are constant of their `apply`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yes, I was really wrong about this (don't understand why I had this wrong impression)... good to know from now on. https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback